# Change the text of UINavigationController not working in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have an app which has 5 `UIViewControllers` and the `rootViewController` is attached to a `UINavigationController` and the others are connected by `segues`. Now, I want to add a title to the `UINavigationController`. I have tried different things in `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear`:

```
self.text = "Hello" // Runtime Error
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Hello" // Runtime Error
self.navigationController?.visibleViewController.title = "Hello"   // Runtime Error
```

The `UIViewController` that I am calling this is like this:

```
class LoginTypeActivityViewController: PPViewController{
}
```

Where, `PPViewController` is declared like this:

```
class PPViewController: UIViewController{
}
```

The runtime error is:

```
2014-10-13 17:21:27.878 mobilepay[29387:1382271] -[Swift._NSContiguousString set]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b6b33d0
2014-10-13 17:21:27.881 mobilepay[29387:1382271] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Swift._NSContiguousString set]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b6b33d0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00bb5df6 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0083fa97 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00bbda75 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 277
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00b069c7 ___forwarding___ + 1047
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00b0658e _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
5   UIFoundation                        0x067eeb91 __NSStringDrawingEngine + 29221
6   UIFoundation                        0x067e784d -[NSString(NSExtendedStringDrawing) drawWithRect:options:attributes:context:] + 171
7   UIKit                               0x013be151 -[UILabel _drawTextInRect:baselineCalculationOnly:] + 6626
8   UIKit                               0x013bbe30 -[UILabel drawTextInRect:] + 581
9   UIKit                               0x013be256 -[UILabel drawRect:] + 98
10  UIKit                               0x0123354b -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:] + 519
11  QuartzCore                          0x01077d51 -[CALayer drawInContext:] + 118
12  QuartzCore                          0x01077c87 _ZL16backing_callbackP9CGContextPv + 96
13  QuartzCore                          0x00f5c7ae CABackingStoreUpdate_ + 2788
14  QuartzCore                          0x01077c1f ___ZN2CA5Layer8display_Ev_block_invoke + 93
15  QuartzCore                          0x010ad406 x_blame_allocations + 15
16  QuartzCore                          0x01077a85 _ZN2CA5Layer8display_Ev + 1591
17  QuartzCore                          0x01077cd6 -[CALayer _display] + 33
18  QuartzCore                          0x01077446 _ZN2CA5Layer7displayEv + 142
19  QuartzCore                          0x01077cb0 -[CALayer display] + 33
20  QuartzCore                          0x0106bee6 _ZN2CA5Layer17display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 322
21  QuartzCore                          0x0106bf6c _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 38
22  QuartzCore                          0x00fca676 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 284
23  QuartzCore                          0x00fcba3c _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 392
24  QuartzCore                          0x00fcc108 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
25  CoreFoundation                      0x00ad8fbe __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
26  CoreFoundation                      0x00ad8f00 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 400
27  CoreFoundation                      0x00ace93a __CFRunLoopRun + 1226
28  CoreFoundation                      0x00ace1ab CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
29  CoreFoundation                      0x00acdfdb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
30  GraphicsServices                    0x0317124f GSEventRunModal + 192
31  GraphicsServices                    0x0317108c GSEventRun + 104
32  UIKit                               0x011a8e16 UIApplicationMain + 1526
33  mobilepay                           0x001410de top_level_code + 78
34  mobilepay                           0x0014111b main + 43
35  libdyld.dylib                       0x03ad7ac9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

What can be the error? I am stuck since the last 5 hours here.

I am trying to set the title different in different `UIViewControllers`.

Answer (score 0):

In your viewDidLoad(), type:

```
title = "Hello World"
```